# PowerShell regular expression /regex to replace a comma separated string of text

Tags: regex, powershell

My current problem is that I have a string like this:

```
A1=ExampleText,B2=ExampleText,B2=ExampleText
```

I want to replace the 'T1=' and 'B2=' with a blank space so I send up with a string like this:

```
ExampleText,ExampleText,ExampleText
```

I have tried to use this piece of code

```
"A1=ExampleText,B2=ExampleText,B2=ExampleText" -replace '=([$,]*)'
```

This only removes the = sign, also want to remove the A1,B2...

```
A1ExampleText,B2ExampleText,B2ExampleText
```

can anyone please provide a regular expression to do that and explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
\w+=
```

will do it for you.

It simply matches a number if *word characters* (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 & _), at least one, followed by an equal sign. Replacing that with `''` should do it.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dX7jO4/1).